# React doesn't render all elements of a carousel

Tags: reactjs

I m working on a carousel which has as two slides , each slide has four cards. The problem is that React renders only the first slide, when I click on the button to get the next slide, it just doesn't get rendered.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Slider,Container,CategoriesContainer,CategoryButton} from "./StyledComponents"
import Slide from "./Components/Slide"
import { TopSalesData } from '../../../../../Database/DummyDatabase';


const Events = [TopSalesData[0], TopSalesData[1]];
const delay = 7500;
const Categories = ["Carti", "Carti Straine"]

const TopSalesCarousel = () => {
    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
    const timeoutRef = React.useRef(null);
    
    function resetTimeout() {
        if (timeoutRef.current) {
          clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        resetTimeout();
        timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(
        () =>
        setIndex((prevIndex) =>
          prevIndex === Events.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
        ),
      delay
        );

        return () => {resetTimeout();};
    }, [index]);

    return (
        <Container> 
            <Slider style={{ transform: `translate3d(${-index * 100}%, 0, 0)` }}>
                {
                    Events.map((_,index)=><Slide items = {Events[index]}></Slide>)
                }
            </Slider>

            <CategoriesContainer>
                {Events.map((_, idx) => (
                    <CategoryButton key={idx} onClick={() => {setIndex(idx);}}>{Categories[idx]}</CategoryButton>
                ))}
            </CategoriesContainer>    
            
    </Container>
        
    );

}       
export default TopSalesCarousel
```

I used useEffect and useState hooks.

Slide component source code:

```
import { RootContainer } from "./StyledComponents";
import TopSaleCard from "../TopSaleCard";

const Slide = (props) => {
    return(
        <RootContainer>
             {  props.items.map((item, index)=>
                    <TopSaleCard 
                        key={index} 
                        title={item.name} 
                        img = {item.img} 
                        position = {item.position}>
                    </TopSaleCard>
                    )
                }    
        </RootContainer>   
    )       
}
export default Slide
```

Slider source code:

```
export const Slider = styled.div`
    white-space: nowrap;
    background:transparent;
    height:26rem;
    margin-top:1rem;
    transition: ease 3000ms;
    `
```

Comment: Could you show the code for `Slider` and `Slide`?

Comment: Yes, I added the code for slide and slider

Comment: I guess wherever you have used map function, try to add `return` statement into even if it is a nested.

Comment: I don't see a code that would offset the slides. It looks like all the slides are rendered in the same place and the others are obscured by the first. Could you check in the dev tools?

Comment: I solved the problem , I added the "display:flex"  property to slider design.